# Centering dropdown menu in CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, center

I am having trouble centering the following CSS dropdown menu:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: none;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}

.container a {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: green;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}

.container a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: none;
  color: green;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: none;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: green;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: none;
  color: green;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

I have tried using position: absolute, and entering values for "top" and left" however this only seems to move the text, and loses the dropdown functionality.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Full code here:

gist.github.com/ruslan024/1a7d2ce4936a35369221a8f0e41c5dd7

Comment: Can you include your HTML too, thanks

Comment: It seems there is a limit on how much code I can add, so I tried to only include the main parts of the drop down menu.

Comment: There is no limit to code, that I'm aware of, if you insert all concerned code within an embedded Code Snippet.

Comment: Use a **Code Snippet** - take a look at your editor toolbar (where **Bold** and *Italic* formatting options can be found); it is the "file icon" with the "code brackets" (`<>`) on it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? Without the full HTML formatted into a snippet (not just some 3rd party gist) I had to make some assumptions. Apart from that it was just a few CSS tweaks.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
}

.container > a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  color: green;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: none;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: green;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: none;
  color: green;
}

.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
  <div href="" class="dropbtn">Resources
      <span class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="market data bank.html">Market Data Bank</a>
        <a href="stock quotes.html">Stock Quotes</a>
        <a href="financial tools.html">Finacial Tools</a>
      </span>
  </div>
  <div href="" class="dropbtn">Services
      <span class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="planning and guidance.html">Planning and Guidance</a>
        <a href="portfolio advisory services.html">Portfolio Advisory Services</a>
        <a href="wealth planning.html">Wealth Planning</a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
</div>
```